# The importance of names in the bible

Tags: cultural-analysis

It seems that names are taken with special care in the Bible:

THE THIRD COMMANDMENT:You shall not take the name of the Lord your God in vain, for the Lord will not hold him guiltless who takes His name in vain" (Exodus 20:7)

- Jacob's name is changed to Israel (Genesis 32:22-32).
- Saul's name is changed to Paul (Acts 13:9).

See other examples HERE: https:[//www.gotquestions.org/name-change.html](https://www.gotquestions.org/name-change.html).

MY QUESTION IS: Why are names taken so carefully in the Bible? Is it tradition or God's will?

Comment: It was the Hebrew culture.  This aspect of Hebrew culture is found in many other cultures as well such as the Arab world.

Comment: See https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/48849/matthew-69-what-is-the-meaning-of-hallowed-be-thy-name/48850#48850  and  https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/81706/does-the-term-name-of-the-lord-in-ex-20-and-lev-22-refer-to-more-than-its-lite/81712#81712

Answer (score 1):

Names in the Bible tend to fit the narrative in terms of their meanings.

Jacob's name is changed from one meaning "supplanter/deceiver," to one meaning "God prevails" after he had wrestled with God, and God had blessed Jacob.  This new name gave him a new opportunity; a new reputation.

But with respect to God's "name," there is an additional concept of honor or reputation attached.  In other words, one's "name" is representative of one's *character.*

When the commandment says "thou shalt not *take* the name of the LORD thy God in vain," it could be translated from the Hebrew as "thou shalt not *bear* the name of the LORD thy God in vain."  In other words, this "name" represents God's honor.  If one claims to be a follower of God, God asks that one honor God through obedience to His commandments--not merely having a vain religion which *says* one thing but *does* another.